# Why fixed element is stuck inside its parent element?

Tags: css, position, fixed

I found only opposite problems with Google where people wanted the fixed element to stay inside it's parent. My problem is that I can't get fixed element out of it's parent element.

This css moves fixed-element at the bottom of it's parent and acts like position absolute.
There's no positioning on any parent or grandparent.

I checked from inspect styles and nothing is overwriting it.

What could possibly cause this?

```
li.fixed-element {
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background:#fff;
  z-index: 100000000000000000000;
}
```

Edit. Here's the html. It's from Gravity Forms plugin.

```
<form>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li id="field_2_2" class="fixed-element gfield gfield_price gfield_price_2_ gfield_total gfield_total_2_ field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
                        <label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_2">Total</label>
                        <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_total">
                            <span class="ginput_total ginput_total_2" aria-live="polite">0,00 €</span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="input_2" id="input_2_2" class="gform_hidden">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add your html code too

Comment: Using just the given CSS and a simple ul structure the li with that class fixes to the bottom of the viewport as desired. Please put up a working snippet which shows the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually it gets positioned to the form element as it was position absolute.

Comment: @A Haworth I can't reproduce the problem with html and css.